# Group Label value prefixes by Delimiter in Prometheus

Tags: jenkins, prometheus, grafana, promql

I am working on creating Grafana dashboards that display data from Jenkins collected  with Thanos/Prometheus. Each jenkins job is labeled by branch and tag from github. This means that there are lots of builds that are similar. EG: `testbuild1/branch1`,
`testbuild1/branch2`, `testbuild1/1.2.3` etc.  these are defined by the label name `jenkins_job`

I want to aggregate the metrics in each unique build with one prometheus query and have them relabeled.

For instance, I want all branches and tags of `testbuild1` to be combined into one metric so I can count all failures for each build. I thought I could do this by treating the "/" as a delimiter but I cannot get the query right.

so if `testbuild1/branch1` had 1 failure  `testbuild1/branch2` had 3 failures and `testbuild1/1.2.3` had 4 failures. the new metric would read `testbuild1` with 8 failures.

I tried something like this `label_join(default_jenkins_builds_duration_milliseconds_summary_count{ status="FAILURE"}, "jenkins_job", "/", "jenkins_job")`

I think I might be misunderstanding the query language. How would I get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [label_replace](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#label_replace) function. For example, the following query extracts `jenkins_job` label part until the first `/` char and stores it instead of the original `jenkins_job` label value:

```
label_replace(
default_jenkins_builds_duration_milliseconds_summary_count{ status="FAILURE"},
  "jenkins_job",
  "$1",
  "jenkins_job",
  "([^/]+)/.+"
)
```

If you want counting summary failures over multiple jenkins jobs over the given period of time (let say over the last hour (1h)), then the following promql query must be used:

```
sum(
  label_replace(
    increase(
default_jenkins_builds_duration_milliseconds_summary_count{ status="FAILURE"}[1h]),
    "jenkins_job",
    "$1",
    "jenkins_job",
    "([^/]+)/.+"
  )
) by (jenkins_job)
```

This function uses [sum()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#sum) aggregate function.

Note that the `label_replace()` function is applied after the [increase()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#increase), since the query won't work as expected otherwise - see [these docs](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#implicit-query-conversions) for details.